# React Native Testing with a single code base

Tags: react-native, cypress, webdriver-io, detox

If we have a single codebase for react-native-web and mobile apps (Android and iOS) how should we handle the e2e tests. Is it possible to handle the tests also using a single code base ? 
I saw that we can do this with WebdriverIO and CodeceptJS both.
But most of the time seems its handled with 3 different tests. Normally Cypress for handle web part, and appium / detox to handle the mobile part

Is there anyone who done this practically in there projects. Can you point me in the correct direction to find the best tool or the approach

Comment: I have a codebase with React Native + React Native Web + NextJS, and I use jest and Enzyme for unit testing, can also use React Testing Library. I have 2 jest config files. The web one, `jest.config.web.js` target `.web.[ext]` files with web setup, ignoring react native packages in module transformation, mapping `react-native` to `react-nativve-web`, with a `setupAfterEnv.web.js` where I put global mock and setup for web. Same for jest config for native, `jest.config.js`. A normal file is run on both test. If there is Platform logic inside, just add Platform logic in test to match it.

Comment: I don't have experience with cypress and detox, but I know it is a matter of setup an entry point for web, or for native. And at the end, it's the output of React components that is being tested. Setting up web will ensure that the process uses React Native Web to transform the React Component into Tags usable by Web Browsers HTML. Native setting will just keep the React Component with native Tags, usable by Android XML for example.